# Going from $1\le\frac{x}{\sin x}\le\frac1{\cos x}$ to $1\ge\frac{\sin x}{x}\ge\cos x$ by multiplying $\frac{\sin(x)^2} {x^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I want to take the reciprocal of this inequality
$$1 \le \frac{x}{\sin(x)} \le \frac{1} {\cos(x)}$$
to get the following
$$1 \ge \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ge \cos(x)$$

I know that I just can switch the numerator and denominator.
But I want to solve it by multiplying each side with $\frac{\sin(x)^2} {x^2}$, just how I would do it with a normal equation. The problem is that I can't remove the $\sin(x)^2$ from the two other parts.

Is it even possible like this, or am I missing something?

Greetings 
Lizz4rd

Edit: Wrong signs

Comment: Your first inequality isn't generally true. What is the domain of values of $x$ you are considering?

Comment: You can't take reciprocals and preserve an inequality. For instance $\frac 12 < 1$ but $2 \not< 1$.

Comment: Beware. Reciprocal means $\leq ~~ \longrightarrow ~~ \geq$ et vicem.

Comment: @EllipticCurve Provided both sides have the same sign.

Comment: @paw88789 Yes, indeed!

Comment: @UmbertoP. x can have values between 0 and pi/2.
Sorry, I missed that I have to change the signs. I edited it to be correct now.